# Insert space in MySQL column value

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have a value like "this - is - a -comment". However I need to run an update statement to add a space after the last - (-comment above should be - comment)

Any able to help me with an update statement?

Comment: sql-server is a tag for a DBMS by Microsoft, do you want a solution for both MySQL and sql-server?

Comment: Specify one RDBMS. If MySQL - specify version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution, there may be more efficient ways of doing it but this is one way that avoids more complicated solutions like using regular expressions.

```
update YourTable SET [ColumnValue] = REPLACE(REPLACE([ColumnValue],'- ', '-'), '-', '- ')
```

So what this is doing is setting all instances of '- ' to '-' first, in order to make the spacing between hyphens/words consistent throughout your whole string. It then takes all instances of '-' and transfers them to '- '.

The reason behind doing this double replace is to avoid adding extra spaces between the hyphen and the word.

If you just did:

```
update YourTable SET [ColumnValue] = REPLACE([ColumnValue], '-', '- ')
```

You would end up with multiple spaces between the hyphen and the words (in the case of "- is" and "- a").